# Cannot connect socket.io to frontend javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, express, socket.io

I am developing a website that needs to catch events emitted from server.js into a javascript file that handles the frontend. Obviously I am using socket.io (i said that in the title) and the method I am using to connect the backend and the frontend is the following:

```
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script src="js/chat.js"></script>
```

Then in the chat.js file i just decalre a const like this:

```
const socket = io();
```

and then I use the method

```
socket.on('event', (data) =>{
});
```

eccc...

This method does not seem to work though.
It says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).
(Also says that io is not defined but it's normal if it cannot find the socket.io file).

I have followed a tutorial that has done the same and it does not work anymore as well.

On my server.js the code looks like this:

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDB = require('./config/dbConnection');



const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const io = socketio(server);
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const User = require('./model/user');


const moment = require('moment');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3500;
```

Thanks to anyone who answers.

Comment: are you sure this `/socket.io/socket.io.js` is the right path? you could try and load it from a CDN to check if it works: `<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I’ll try as soon as possible!